# O(n*n*n!) = O((n+2)!)

Tags: factorial

I am going through a programming time complexity learning os a recursive function to find all the combinations of the given string. This is stated by the author. I am trying to figure out how `n*n*n! == (n+2)!`

```
O(n*n*n!) = O((n+2)!)
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You seem to be confusing two different things $n^2\cdot n!=O((n+2)!)$ does not mean $n^2\cdot n!= (n+2)!$.  The former is true; the latter is not.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two very different things in your question.  It is not true that $n*n*n!=(n+2)!$.  It is true that $O(n*n*n!) \in O((n+2)!)$ because $(n+2)!=(n+2)(n+1)n!=n^2n!+$terms like $n\cdot n!$ and $n!$ where the later terms are ignorable.  The big O notation hides a lot of things.  It is only interested in the leading term.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simpler or more intuitive definitions for the [big $\mathcal O$ notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) is this: $f(x) \in \mathcal O (g(x))$ if and only if

$$\limsup_{x \to \infty} \left| \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right| < \infty$$

(It need not be $\infty$ but that's likely the relevant point for your application.) Then, notice two things. First, this does not necessitate $f=g$; it's a characterization of growth rate. Next, we see by applying the definition of factorial that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{n \cdot n \cdot n!}{(n+2)!} &= n^2 \cdot \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(2)(1)}{(n+2)(n+1)(n)(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(2)(1)} \\
&=\frac{n^2}{(n+2)(n+1)}
\end{align}$$

When you see this simplification, the limit $n \to \infty$ is obviously $1$ since the bottom is also a quadratic in $n$, allowing you to reach the desired conclusion.

Thus, this means that whenever $f \in \mathcal O (n^2n!)$ we also have $f \in \mathcal O((n+2)!)$.